# Create function to add such that add(1,2)(3,...k)(1,2,3)...(n) should sum all numbers

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have been looking for a way to create an 'add' function such that :

```
add(1,2) //returns 1+2= 3
add(1)(2,3)(4) // returns 10
add(1)(2,3)(4)(5,6)(7,8,9) //returns 45
```

I am able to create add method if I know the number of arguments we have, for e.g.:

```
const add5 = a => b => c => d => e => a+b+c+d+e;
```

So, if I used add5(1)(2)(3)(4)(5), this will give me the expected output.

But the problem is how to tackle the problem if we have to return sum of 'N' parameters.

TIA !

Comment: Not possible in the general case unless `toString` coercion is allowed on the result of calling `add`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Can you provide a code snippet for the same? How exactly should we go about it ?

Comment: Can you explain WHY do you need this?

Comment: Not sure how you expect a function to return a value and a function simultaneously. Can the return value be stored to an output variable instead of returned directly?

Comment: @AndrewShmig was asked in an interview. Couldn't solve it then :/

Comment: @chiliNUT : Yes, we can save it in a variable as well, if that helps.

Comment: instead of searching such way use javascript objects like list to store n number of element inside it and pass it to function and inside a function Extract the list and do  whatever operation you need

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible in the general case unless `toString` coercion is allowed on the result of calling `add` (or unless the number of calls is known in advance):

```js
function add(...next) {
  let count = 0;
  // return a callable function which, when coerced to a string,
  // returns the closure's `count`:
  function internalAdd(...next) {
    count += next.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
    return internalAdd;
  }
  internalAdd.toString = () => count;
  return internalAdd(...next);
}

console.log('' + add(1,2)) //returns 1+2= 3
console.log('' + add(1)(2,3)(4)) // returns 10
console.log('' + add(1)(2,3)(4)(5,6)(7,8,9)) //returns 45
```

Comment: Try not using a mutable `count` variable that is shared across multiple functions